# How to get numeric range between row value SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table which shows Grades and percentages.

Now I want to run query on table which fetch Grade between these percentages.
Example if a student get 72% I want to show the Grade as `C`.
How to get Grade from table?

Please refer this table picture:

[image]

Comment: If a student gets 72%, which Grade will you offer, `B` or `C` ?

Comment: obviously he will get C grade coz B grade start from 75

Comment: which database you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Drop Table Grades
Drop Table Students

Create Table Students (Name Varchar(200), Percentage Numeric(5,2))
Insert Students Values ('John', 0.00)
Insert Students Values ('Jane', 38.00)
Insert Students Values ('Joe', 45.00)
Insert Students Values ('Greg', 50.00)
Insert Students Values ('Buck', 55.00)
Insert Students Values ('Harold', 60.00)
Insert Students Values ('Jack', 65.00)
Insert Students Values ('Bill', 68.00)
Insert Students Values ('Gerald', 75.00)
Insert Students Values ('Steve', 79.00)
Insert Students Values ('Walter', 85.00)
Insert Students Values ('Mike', 92.00)
Insert Students Values ('Mary', 100.00)
Insert Students Values ('Mark', 101.00)
Select * From Students

Create Table Grades (Grade Char(2), Percentage Numeric(5,2))
Go
Insert Grades Values ('A*', 101.00)
Insert Grades Values ('A', 85.00)
Insert Grades Values ('B', 75.00)
Insert Grades Values ('C', 65.00)
Insert Grades Values ('D', 55.00)
Insert Grades Values ('E', 45.00)
Insert Grades Values ('F', 0.00)

Select S.*, G.Grade
    From
        (
        Select  *, IsNull(Lead(Percentage) Over (Order By Percentage), (Select Max(Percentage)+.01 From Grades)) NextPercentage 
            From Grades ) G
    Join Students S On S.Percentage >= G.Percentage And S.Percentage < G.NextPercentage
```

Comment: @NaveedAhmed : If this answer solves your problem, you can accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY Percentage DESC` with `<=` the percentage in WHERE and `TOP 1 Grade` will given the expected result

```
CREATE TABLE #GradeMaster (Grade VARCHAR(2), Percentage DECIMAL(5,2))

INSERT INTO #GradeMaster
SELECT 'A*', 101 UNION
SELECT 'A', 85 UNION
SELECT 'B', 75 UNION
SELECT 'C', 65 UNION
SELECT 'D', 55 UNION
SELECT 'E', 45 UNION
SELECT 'F', 0 

SELECT TOP 1 Grade
FROM #GradeMaster 
WHERE Percentage <= 72
ORDER BY Percentage DESC

DROP TABLE #GradeMaster
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  select grade from table1 where precentage in (
  select max(percentage) from table1 where 72 > percentage);
```

You can substitute 72 for whatever score you like. There may be a way to do it without the 2 selects, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a order by limit 1

```
select grade from my_table
where  percentage <= 72 
order by percentage desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there might also be a student table and assignment table ... I would think the lookup query would look something like this.  The below will give you all students regardless of whether they have any graded assignments.  Alternatively, you could join the student table directly if you have an overall grade already aggregated.

```
SELECT
S.*,
A.*,
G.grade
FROM
Student S
LEFT OUTER JOIN Assignment A ON S.Student_id = A.Student_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Grade G ON A.Percentage >= G.Percentage AND A.Percentage < G.Percentage
```